# What should I do to improve heroku's response time, as it is very slow, crashing the application?

Tags: ios, asp.net, react-native

Heroku is taking a long time to load the information, as if it had loaded too much slowing down the system.

I'm trying to change the plan (for a more robust package) But I would like an explanation on how to do this procedure.